# Partial Laplace Transform Inversion

Tags: laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I am trying to invert the function
$$
F(s) = \frac{s^{\beta/2-1}}{ 2 \pi }  K_0 ( y s^{\beta/2} ) \quad  0<\beta \leq 1
$$
I am using the Basset representation of the Bessel K function as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\left. \frac{{{  e}^{  i {{s}^{\frac{\beta}{2}}} u z}}}{\sqrt{{{u}^{2}}+1}}du\right.} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\left. {{  e}^{ i {{s}^{\frac{\beta}{2}}} z\, \sinh(y)}}d y\right.}
$$
Is it possible to switch places of the integrals in the double integral representation:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \oint_{Ha} ds {{s}^{\beta-1}}\, \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }{\left. {{ e}^{  i {{s}^{\frac{\beta}{2}}}\, \operatorname{sinh}(y) z+s t}}dy\right.}
$$